# Linking yaml-cpp in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, linker-errors, static-linking, yaml-cpp

I am trying to use yaml-cpp in my project. I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

I downloaded the code from github (https://github.com/jbeder/yaml-cpp)

I went through the tutorial on the github page and ended up with a folder in "Program Files (x86)" called "YAML_CPP". It has a subfolder called "include" with the header files and another called "lib" with a single .lib file.

The cmake command I used for the tutorial was:
`cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -DYAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..`

I start up a new C++ console project in Visual Studio and I open **"Project" -> "Properties"** and use these settings:

**"Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "General" -> "Additional Include Directories"** = "C:\Program Files %28x86%29\YAML_CPP\include" (I add the folder with "select folder" dialog)

**"Configuration Properties" -> "Linker" -> "General" -> "Additional Library Directories"** = "C:\Program Files %28x86%29\YAML_CPP\lib" (I add the folder with "select folder" dialog)

**"Configuration Properties" -> "Linker" -> "Input" -> "Additional Dependencies"** = "yaml-cppd.lib" (the name of the lib in the "lib" folder in the "YAML_CPP" folder, this is added manually).

Below is my basic test, it compiles without issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Here is where I get errors:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main()
{
    YAML::Emitter out;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

```
1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl YAML::Emitter::Emitter(void)" (__imp_??0Emitter@YAML@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main

1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl YAML::Emitter::~Emitter(void)" (__imp_??1Emitter@YAML@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main

1>C:\Users\Fridrik\source\repos\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong when it comes to linking, but I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `__declspec(dllimport)` means its looking for an import library (.lib) that goes with a dll. This is odd if you turned off building of shared libs.

Comment: I tried building with -DYAML_BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON as well (I was testing different configurations), that produces a different output and then I get a .dll file in the "YAML_CPP" folder in Program Files.

But I agree, I don't understand the dllimport errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if you have resolved this or not yet, but I have just resolved this for myself.

There is a macro within `include/yaml-cpp/dll.h` that checks if `YAML_CPP_STATIC_DEFINE` is defined.

Where it is not defined, it will attempt to import the necessary code using `__declspec(dllimport)` which imports the code from a .dll

Where it is defined, it won't look for a .dll file.

You need to update your code to the below to ensure the library operates as a static library, opposed to a shared library where it relies on a .dll file.

```
#include <iostream>

#define YAML_CPP_STATIC_DEFINE
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"

int main()
{
    YAML::Emitter out;
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```