# Add YAML-CPP Lib in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unresolved-external, yaml-cpp

I have built the yaml-cppd.lib (debug) with cmake successfully, and then configurate the Visual Studio 2019 as follows, but still get "unresolved external symbol" error.

1. Add include path "$(SolutionDir)..\yaml-cpp\include;" (it is correct) for "Include Directories" and "Reference Directories" in "VC++ Directories", and VS then could find the "yaml.h".
2. Add Library path "$(SolutionDir)..\yaml-cpp\build\Debug;" for "Library Directories" in "VC++ Directories"
3. Add "yaml-cppd.lib" to "Linker->input->Additional Dependencies"

Then I trid to build my solution, but still get "unresolved external symbol" error.

Did I miss any step necessarily?

PS. I follow same steps to install lemon.lib. LEMON works well, but YAML-CPP doesn't.

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/72620626/8509611